# How to know if an old visitor clicked a button in Wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a cookies policy message in the blog i'm building in Wordpress (www.diariodeinversion.es).
This is the code in footer.php

```
<?php if(!isset($_COOKIE['diariodeinversion_newvisitor'])){ ?>
<div id="cookie">   
<!-- Cookies policy message --><input style="margin:0px 0px 0px 10px" type="button" id="toggler" value="OK" onClick="action();" />
</div>
<script>
  function action(){
    document.getElementById('cookie').style.visibility='hidden';
  }
</script>
<?php } ?><!-- End if -->
```

And here is the function in functions.php

```
function set_newuser_cookie(){
  if( !is_admin() && !isset($_COOKIE['diariodeinversion_newvisitor'])) {
    setcookie('diariodeinversion_newvisitor', 1, time()+3600);
  }
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_newuser_cookie' );
```

Nowadays i'm able to distinguish between new and old visitors but is there a way to know if an old visitor hit the OK button in order to not showing the message again in that case?

Thanks in advance!
Jose

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `cookies` & the `IP address` to detect an old user but both can changed.

User can delete the cookies from his browser & also change the IP address since most of the users use dynamic IP address.

When the visitor clicks the button, then check if the visitor already has cookies with him. If not contains then he is a new visitor & send the cookies to the user, if already contains the cookies previously sent by you, then block him.

Comment: Hi Harshit, i already use _cookies_ to distinguish between old and new visitors (as you say, this solution doesn't work in all cases but for me it's okay). My problem now is how to know if an old visitor has already clicked on the OK button or not in order to show or hide the message. Thanks again.

Comment: Edited the answer @jose.